# Combining two arrays using the first array as key(but has duplicates) then adding the second array values that has the matching duplicates

Tags: php, arrays

I want to combine two arrays. First use the first array as the key(combining the duplicates) then add the values from the second array to adjust to the specific keys

```
//first array  
array('1','0','1'); 
//second array 
array('50','10','20');

//output -> first array ('1','0') second array -> ('70','10')
```

removing the duplicates in the first array and adding the corresponding "duplicate" key in the second array values

Comment: Can you add any attempt you've made so far, it shows that you have made some effort to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a result array to collect the outcomes like this:

```
//first array  
$k = array('1','0','1'); 
//second array 
$v = array('50','10','20');

$result = array();

foreach($k as $index => $value) {
    if(!isset($result[$value])) {
        $result[$value] = 0;
    }
    $result[$value] += $v[$index];
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: This is javascript. OPs question is clearly tagged PHP.

Comment: Ah, overlooked that.. will fix it